# Inserting GeoJson Polygon Coordinates with MongoDB and C#?

Tags: c#, tab, mongodb

I'm using GDAL\ogrinfo.exe to read the tab file which includes polygon/LineString/Point coordinates as a stream using the process. I'll store the coordinates in the MongoDB.

My attempt at inserting LineString was a success by using:

`GeoJsonLineStringCoordinates<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>`

I used `GeoJsonPolygonCoordinates<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates` and kept getting the error

`{"A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors.\r\n  location object expected, location array not in correct format"}`

I used the QGIS to check the tab file, if the polygon is a closed one `GeoJsonPolygonCoordinates<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates` done the job no prob. But if the tab file is like the attached image the ex-occurs.

[image: Sample polygon layout from QGIS]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. As I suspected it was simple enough. Need to use `GeoJson.Polygon<TCoordinates> Method (GeoJsonObjectArgs<TCoordinates>, GeoJsonPolygonCoordinates<TCoordinates>)` [GeoJson Polygon](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_GeoJsonObjectModel_GeoJson_Polygon__1.htm)

Some code for reference:

```
        IMongoClient client = new MongoClient(_mongoConnString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(MONGO_DB_NAME);

        var collection = database.GetCollection<MongoFence>(MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME);         

        IndexKeysDefinition<MongoFence> keyLocation = "{ Polygon: '2dsphere' }";                
        var locationIndexModel = new CreateIndexModel<MongoFence>(keyLocation);

        GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates one  = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(-122.335604, 48.390017);
        GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates two = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(-122.333195, 48.390053);
        GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates three = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(-122.333088, 48.391189);
        GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates four = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(-122.335529, 48.39116);
        GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates five = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(-122.335631, 48.390809);
        GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates six = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(-122.335604, 48.390017);

        GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates[] coord_array = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates[] { one, two, three, four, five, six };

        var fenceList = new List<MongoFence>();
        fenceList.Add(new MongoFence
        {
            Name = "1",
            Polygon = GeoJson.Polygon(coord_array)
        });

        await collection.InsertManyAsync(fenceList);
```